# Fat-free php invalid route

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I'm currently having a routing issue with the fat-free framework. After looking around and reading the documentation I've so far been unable to solve it despite it seeming to be a simple problem.

I'm using f3's standard routing format from the root directory:

```
$f3->route(array('GET /', 'GET /index.php'), function($f3) {
    include 'header.html';
    include 'Home/index.html';
    include 'footer.html';
});

//search
$f3->route('GET /Browse', function() {
    include 'Browse/index.html';
});
```

These routes both work correctly and as expected. When I enter localhost on xammp, both return the pages outlined. Both have a file structure:

```
-Root
-index.php
-header.html
-footer.html
--Browse
---index.html
```

After defining a new route I do not wish to have a folder with a index.html file and instead respond by echoing html.

```
$f3->route('GET /Latest',
    function() {
        include 'submit/index.html';
        echo 'This is our home page.';
    }
);
```

When I use the code above, and go to localhost/Latest I'm presented with:

```
Error 404 : Not found
```

My question is how can I allow a response directly from PHP without having a subsequent folder and index.html file.

Thanks and many regards :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the framework [template engine](http://fatfreeframework.com/views-and-templates).

There are various ways to structure your code, but here's a quick basic example:

```
// index.php

$f3->UI='templates/';

$f3->route('GET /home',function($f3){
    $f3->main='home.html';
    $f3->title='Homepage';
    $tpl=Template::instance();
    echo $tpl->render('layout.html');
});

$f3->route('GET /contact',function($f3){
    $f3->main='contact.html';
    $f3->title='Contact us';
    $f3->address='5578 Grant Street Woodbridge, VA 22191';
    $tpl=Template::instance();
    echo $tpl->render('layout.html');
});
```

```
<!-- templates/layout.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>{{ @title }}</title>

<body>
  <include href="header.html"/>
  <main>
    <include href="{{ @main }}"/>
  </main>
  <include href="footer.html"/>
</body>
```

```
<!-- templates/home.html -->
<h1>Hey hey! Welcome home!</h1>
```

```
<!-- templates/contact.html -->
<h1>Our address</h1>
<p>{{ @address }}</p>
```

As for the 404 error, make sure your `.htaccess` file is correctly configured, especially the `RewriteBase` directive. If it's not, every URI other than `/` will throw a 404. See [here](http://fatfreeframework.com/routing-engine#SampleApacheConfiguration) for more details about the setup.

Comment: Ah thanks so much, id upvote but cant on the site until my reputation is higher. But thanks so much i think this is what iv been looking for :)